# Añadir elemento a un array en Java

Tags: java, array

Para empezar decir que para realizar el ejercicio no puedo usar nada de la API de Java ni tipos genéricos.

Mi código debe implementar una interfaz de un conjunto matemático de números enteros, que puede tener 0 elementos. Se hará mediante un array de enteros en esta clase en concreto.

El problema viene a la hora de insertar un nuevo elemento al array. Para el primer conjunto (c1, ver en el programa principal) no tengo absolutamente ningún problema. Cuando el programa principal empieza a llenar el array de c2, todo funciona correctamente hasta que lega al último elemento (no importa la entrada, siempre es el último).

El fallo se da en tiempo de ejecución. No me da ninguna información sobre el mismo, simplemente se queda 'colgado'.

Entonces dispongo de:

```
public class ConjuntoTabla implements Conjunt {
//Descripción general: Implementación en forma de tabla de enteros

//Tabla de enteros ordenada de forma creciente
private int _tablaInt[];

public ConjuntoTabla() {
    this._tablaInt = new int [0];
}

private void setElem(int i, int n) {
    _tablaInt[i] = n;
}

private int getElem(int i) {
    return _tablaInt[i];
}

//Cierto si n pertenece al conjunto
public boolean pertenece(int n) {
    int medio, izq = 0, der = this.nelem()-1;
    boolean encontrado = false;
    while (!encontrado && izq <= der) {
        medio = (izq + der)/2;
        if (n < getElem(medio)) der = medio -1;
        else if (n > getElem(medio)) izq = medio + 1;
        else encontrado = true;
    }
    return encontrado;
}

public int nelem() {
    return (_tablaInt.length);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
String s = "";
for (int i=0; i<nelem(); i++) {
        if (i==0) s = s+getElem(i);
        else s = s + "," + getElem(i);
}
return "[" + s + "]";
}
}
```

Entonces yo quiero tener un método para insertar un nuevo elemento al Conjunto y que lo haga de forma ordenada, esto debería hacerlo el siguiente código:

```
//Se ha añadido n al conjunto ordenadamente
public void añadir(int n)
{
    if (!this.pertenece(n)) {
        int i = this.nelem();
        int aux[] = new int[i+1];
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            aux[j] = getElem(j);
        }
        //Busca la posición donde se debe insertar n
        while (i > 0 && n < getElem(i-1)) {
            aux[i] = getElem(i-1);
            i--;
        }
        aux[i] = n;
        _tablaInt = aux;
    }
}
```

Dispongo del siguiente programa principal para probar la clase. NO puedo realizar ninguna modificación en el mismo

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestConjuntoTabla {
//Lee dos secuencias consecutivas de enteros separadas con '#' y las
//pone en dos conjuntos


public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
Conjunto c1 = new ConjuntoTabla();
Conjunto c2 = new ConjuntoTabla();

System.out.println("Introducir dos secuencias de enteros, separadas por el símbolo: #");

while (s.hasNextInt())
    c1.añadir(s.nextInt());

s.next(); // Salta '#'

while (s.hasNextInt())
    c2.añadir(s.nextInt());

System.out.println("\nc1: " + c1);
System.out.println("c2: " + c2);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema te da exactamente tu código, y dónde?

Comment: En el programa main, al hacer c2.añadir el programa se queda colgado. Al hacer un debug, concretamente puedo ver que se leen y guardan todos los numeros de la secuencia menos el ultimo numero, es en esta iteracion que se queda en 'running' sin hacer nada

Comment: Sí, veo ahora que ya lo habías puesto, disculpa. Normalmente "se queda colgado" significa que está en un bucle infinito, pero en los tres bucles que identifico en `añadir` (el `for` y el `while`de `añadir`, y el `while` de `pertenece`) parece garantizado que van a acabar. La verdad no veo donde puede estar el problema.

Comment: La principal particularidad es que el c1.añadir lo hace perfecto, es decir, todos los métodos hacen lo que debería y el array es rellenado y ordenado por la secuencia entrada por teclado. Sin embargo, es al hacer c2.añadir que falla. Se añaden bien todos los elementos, y ademas de forma ordenada, a excepcion del último, allí se cuelga el programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu programa funciona a las mil maravillas, lo que te está pasando es que no has entendido la lógica del mismo. Tal vez lo que sucede es que no te has dado cuenta que el método `hasNextInt()` de la clase `Scanner` siempre va a devolver `true` si el carácter introducido por teclado es el delimitador por defecto del sistema (espacio en blanco) o si NO introduces ningún carácter (solo presionas ENTER).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo que debes hacer es indicarle al programa que has finalizado la introducción de enteros mandando un carácter que no sea reconocido como entero.

En el ejercicio te dicen que el delimitador es una almohadilla (#). Entonces usa la almohadilla al final de la introducción del segundo grupo de enteros.

Adjunto una implementación propia de tu programa, sin alterar el método `main`, como pides, pero como no sé de donde sacas la clase `Conjunt`, yo la extiendo desde una `Object`, el resultado es el mismo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ConjuntoTabla extends Object {
//Descripción general: Implementación en forma de tabla de enteros
//Tabla de enteros ordenada de forma creciente
  private int _tablaInt[];
  public ConjuntoTabla() {
    this._tablaInt = new int [0];
  }
  private void setElem(int i, int n) {
    _tablaInt[i] = n;
  }
  private int getElem(int i) {
    return _tablaInt[i];
  }
  //Cierto si n pertenece al conjunto
  public boolean pertenece(int n) {
    int medio, izq = 0, der = this.nelem()-1;
    boolean encontrado = false;
    while (!encontrado && izq <= der) {
      medio = (izq + der)/2;
      if (n < getElem(medio)) der = medio -1;
      else if (n > getElem(medio)) izq = medio + 1;
      else encontrado = true;
    }
    return encontrado;
  }
  public int nelem() {
    return (_tablaInt.length);
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int i=0; i<nelem(); i++) {
      if (i==0) s = s+getElem(i);
      else s = s + "," + getElem(i);
    }
    return "[" + s + "]";
  }
  //Se ha añadido n al conjunto ordenadamente
  public void añadir(int n) {
    if (!this.pertenece(n)) {
      int i = this.nelem();
      int aux[] = new int[i+1];
      for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
        aux[j] = getElem(j);
      }
      //Busca la posición donde se debe insertar n
      while (i > 0 && n < getElem(i-1)) {
        aux[i] = getElem(i-1);
        i--;
      }
      aux[i] = n;
      _tablaInt = aux;
    }
  }
}

public class addArrayElement {
  //Lee dos secuencias consecutivas de enteros separadas con '#' y las
  //pone en dos conjuntos
  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    ConjuntoTabla c1 = new ConjuntoTabla();
    ConjuntoTabla c2 = new ConjuntoTabla();
    System.out.println("Introducir dos secuencias de enteros, separadas por el símbolo: #");
    while (s.hasNextInt())
      c1.añadir(s.nextInt());
    s.next(); // Salta '#'
    while (s.hasNextInt())
      c2.añadir(s.nextInt());
    System.out.println("\nc1: " + c1);
    System.out.println("c2: " + c2);
  }
}
```

Puedes ver en la siguiente imagen cómo introduje los datos, usando la almohadilla al finalizar el segundo conjunto, y el resultado del mismo.

[image: Ejemplo de uso del programa]

Espero que esta respuesta te ayude a solucionar tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Vale ya lo entiendo, se quedaba en bucle al no introducirle ningún carácter que distinguiera de un entero! Esta tarde lo probaré y con suerte me podré poner ya con el resto del ejercicio

Comment: Exacto. Ese era el problema. Si la respuesta es satisfactoria (luego que hagas tus pruebas) puedes darla como válida. Saludos

Comment: Sí era eso! Muchas gracias, ya he implementado el resto de métodos (unión, intersección y diferencia) y a priori todo funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Me alegra haber podido ayudar